# is there any way to disable only input not the label in semantic ui Input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

We are using semantic-ui in react for forms.

When I use disable for `Input` , it's disabling both label and input field.

I used like below

```
<Input disabled placeholder='Search' label='Name' />
```

Is there any way to disable only input box not the label??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would assume some CSS class is being added to the label. If so, check their API or apply needed styles yourself

Comment: `<label>Name</label>
<Input placeholder='Search' disabled/>` try with label and input with diff element.

Comment: Yes. it's working. But only with input we can't get it. is it?

Comment: Not able to use required with this method as the red asterisk does not show up unless label in set internally